# Tooling for examine browser window.history

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-history

On some (own) websites it would helpful to get a deeper look into the window.history stack of my browser. Is there a hidden feature, or extension, for major browsers to achieve this?

I will illustrate it, why sometimes some more informations are useful:

[image: history for outlook online]

On some sites, if I use a long press for back-function, I get a list with different locations, represented by the site title. If sites use only one unique title, this is not very helpful. Browser history mixes all tabs together.

Mario

Comment: This would be a Privacy Issue - So, what do you think, is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean? I will have a look into the history of my own active tab in my client.

Comment: Imagine some website could read your entire History API state up until you got to their website. Would you like that idea that they not only have cookies but also a nice bunch of websites you visited previously?

Comment: So I can call history.back() as often as I wan't, but there is no option to predicte the new/old location for security reasons? That's a interesting aspect I never thought about it.

Comment: If you're only interested on the History of your own website, than you can use the History API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState or/and the LocalStorage API

Comment: If you're interested to build a Chrome Extension (since is  *"local"* to the user browser env.) perhaps it's possible but I think you'll need also a database. Like i.e: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/egehpkpgpgooebopjihjmnpejnjafefi?hl=en